# In Java find name of calling method and class

Tags: java, debugging

One of my colleagues decided we needed to print each class and method as they are executed so he promptly typed in the name of each method and class at the start of each method.  This was not a little painful to me so I looked up on the web and came up with:

```
System.out.println(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName()+ " : "+
    new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +" [IN]");
```

This works swell.  Except that now I have been informed that this is unsatisfactory because we are creating the Object for the sole purpose of finding the names and we should "Instead, simply use the class' .class property".  Minor problem, I can't seem to get that to work.

Something else I found on the web was:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()  + " : "+
    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() +" [IN]");
```

which does what I need but somebody suggested it was S-L-O-W, having to do a stack trace.

Does anybody have any good suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to re-create a logging framework from scratch?

Comment: Hovercraft is right - use a logging framework, rather than re-inventing it.  Getting the method name is always slow though, no matter how you do it.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a logging framework, i.e. [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/).

Comment: I turned the slf4j logger code that has "logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(..." and "logger.debug(" into SOP to make simplify the question.  My colleague that added the code also added the logging framework and the same time.

Comment: So if you're using a logging framework, why do you need something extra?  Any decent logging framework will have a built-in way of showing class name and method name.

Comment: Incidentally, your second snippet gets the stack trace twice, which seems overkill to me.  If you just write `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]) + "[IN]";` it should be twice as fast.

Comment: It sounds like we probably have exactly what we need already there, all we have to do is configure things appropriately. I'll have to beat up the other guy to get this set up.  They pulled me for this one module and I assumed he knew what he was doing. (He really knows his stuff in other areas, I guess he is not very solid in this part, however.)  Thanks for your input, everybody.

Comment: Can't edit my comment now - but obviously my last comment has the `)` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed nobody answered the question, so I wrote something to time the two versions with a hard coded version as a control.  These functions were called a million times on a 2998 MHz, SPARC-T4 with 64 bit, Java 1.8.0_91.

```
public String findFunc1()
{
    Class myCls=new Object(){}.getClass();

    String ret=myCls.getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName()+ " : "
              +myCls.getEnclosingMethod().getName()+ " [IN]";
    return ret;
}
public String findFunc2()
{
    StackTraceElement mySTE=Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];
    String ret=mySTE.getClassName() + " : "+ mySTE.getMethodName() + " [IN]";
    return ret;
}
public String findFunc3()
{
    String ret="TimeLog"+ " : "+ "findFunc3" + " [IN]";
    return ret;
}
```

They were called as follows:

```
public static void time1() {
    System.out.print("new Object version ");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String ret;
    TimeLog prog=new TimeLog();

    for(int ii=0; ii<1*1000*1000; ii++) {
        ret=prog.findFunc1();
    }
    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Elapsed msec="+totalTime);
}
```

This gives:

```
new Object version Elapsed msec=13923
StackTrace version Elapsed msec=13459
Constant   version Elapsed msec=13
```

The two versions consume similar amounts of time but the hardcoded version is 1000 times faster.

Comment: Lovely.  I had no idea it would be that much slower. I imagine a logging framework has to go through a similar process to find out the name of the caller.  I can't believe Java does not have something akin to __FILE__ and __func__.  Yes, In C, those are implemented in the preprocessor but that does not mean they could not be made available to the compiler by other means. I guess that is the way it goes.